# Select all children bones in Pose mode using Python

Tags: python, armature

I needed a script that selects all children of multiple bones in pose mode. I must admit that my solution was very clumsy but helped in a particular situation =D
So now I wonder how to do it the right, more elegant way? (basically how would you select all children, of any amount of selected bones?)
I've put a loop with the number greater than the number of possible children. (I knew that the number of children will always be lower than 15, so my loop always selected all. But it feels very wrong =D )

```
import bpy
it = 15

while it > 0:
bpy.ops.pose.select_hierarchy(direction='CHILD', extend=True)
it -= 1
```

Comment: Do you want just the immediate children of the selected bones, or do you also want the children of the children and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will select all child bones from parent bones that share the same name as the ones in the list variable `PARENT_BONES`, provided that the mode is `POSE` mode.

```py
import bpy

ARMATURE = "metarig"
PARENT_BONES = ["upper_arm.L", "upper_arm.R"]

if bpy.context.mode == "POSE":
    for b in bpy.data.armatures[ARMATURE].bones:
        if b.name in PARENT_BONES:
            for c in b.children_recursive:
                c.select = True
```

[image]

If you'd like to automatically go into pose mode and get rid of the check mode line, replace the check mode line with `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="POSE")` to go into pose mode, regardless of which mode it is.

Answer (score 0):

this script worked for me

```
import bpy

armature = bpy.context.active_object
bone = armature.data.bones[bpy.context.active_bone.name]

children = []
for child in bone.children_recursive:
    children.append(child.name)

for child in children:
    armature.data.bones[child].select = True
```